# How to resolve this error Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I wrote a console application `helloworld.java` and ran `javac helloworld.java`,and then `java helloworld`. This worked fine.

I then created a package `com.abc.project` and moved helloworld.java into it(the package import statement is correctly generated which is `package com.abc.project;`). And then i ran `javac helloworld.java` this worked also fine and generated the class properly.

However, when I ran `java com.abc.project.helloworld` from the console, it threw an "class not found" error.

Please can anyone advise what is the problem?

Comment: "hellowrold.java", "helloword.java"? Really? Make sense damnit!

Comment: You need to include all the files in your classpath and make sure that the package structure matches the directory that the files are in.

Comment: Did u set classpath before running it ?

Comment: `I wrote a console application hellowrold.java. I ran javac helloword.java and then java helloworld. This worked fine.` Are you sure? :-)

Comment: sorry for the typos. i use eclipse and suppose eclipse will configure the class path automatically? do i need to manually configure the class path?

Comment: eclipse doesn't come into picture when you are using cmd line javac and java to execute your program ! If you run it from eclipse then only eclipse will take care of it !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running

`java -cp ABSOLUTE_PATH com.abc.project.helloworld`

Where ABSOLUTE_PATH refers to the directory where the class files along with packages are present. say it is `bin` directory where the class files are generated along with same directory structure as source files

Comment: For a long time now, the current working directory is on the classpath automatically if you don't manually provide a classpath yourself. I can accept your answer as correct if you replace '.' with an absolute path.

Comment: Oh, I knew it. but, forgot it. Thanks! I have updated the answer.

Comment: Okay, but to say "ABSOLUTE_SRC_PATH" is still confusing, that makes it seem like you are referring to the directory with the source files and not the class files ;) And when you refer to an absolute path, it is of course no longer mandatory to run from the root of the classpath itself.

Comment: @Gimby you are a very good reviewer ;) Changed it. I'm not very good in writing.

Comment: Well then I'm going to add one more complaint, you have to explain what ABSOLUTE_PATH is, because otherwise c:\windows or any other irrelevant folder also applies ;)

Comment: @Gimby Does it ok now?

Comment: That depends on if Mullex understands it, you're not actually writing the answer for my benefit ;)

Answer (score 0):

First Please name Class with Capital Letter like HelloWorld.java

If you are in a folder '/myjava' in cmd and your .java files is in this folder then do this in cmd

```
D:\\myjava\:> javac -d HelloWorld.java
```

This will create correct package Structure for you
Then don't go anywhere from the same location do this

```
D:\\myjava\:>  java com.abc.project.HelloWorld
```

It should work fine!!