# My HelloWorld Program in Java not working

Tags: java

I am new to Java and its my first program in Java, I am trying to run HelloWorldApp program but its giving an error

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin>javac HelloWorldApp.java"
HelloWorldApp.java:5: error while writing HelloWorldApp: HelloWorldApp: HelloWorldApp.class (Access is denied)
public class HelloWorldApp(
1 error
```

I wrote the given code in NotePad and saved that in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin

```
public class HelloWorldApp{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but why did you decide to place your code inside `bin` directory? Any special reason for that?

Answer (score 4):

Put in a folder where administrator rights isn't required. Eg on your desktop. Then open cmd.exe and type `cd C:\path\to\file`. Finally use the same javac command.

Answer (score 2):

Run your command prompt with administrative privilege.

Comment: It has compiled now but has generated this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorldApp/class Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorldApp.class
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
..................

Comment: @Yasir This is subject for another question which you should ask after searching and reading questions about similar problem like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22605831/1393766

Comment: These all errors are related to access of the location your code is placed. It is recommended to pull your code from bin directory to some other directory like on desktop( or any other where permission is not a problem).

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says access denied. Get admin rights for the java folder or place your class file in a different directory for which you have admin rights and try to run.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to folder where You put class file. Move file to another folder where you have proper permission or run that command as administrator.